# how can i get real time value in node-js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote the code to receive data from the device using serial communication device with window.

I can see the data in Console window in eclipse and save data in txt file.

I want to see real-time value and know when did which value was sent

How can I get real time value? Let me know How to write code.

Below is my code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var UrlParser = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
     console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });                 

var port = new SerialPort("COM32" , { 
    baudRate:9600,
});

port.on("open" , function(){                
    console.log('open success');
});

port.on('data', function(data) {            
    converted_data = parseFloat(data);
    console.log(converted_data);    
    fs.appendFile('save.txt',converted_data + '\r\n',function(err) {
        if(err) 
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log('data>txt');
    });
});

port.write("mon 1\n", function(){           
    console.log('write to device');
});

app.get('/data', function (req,res) {       
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/data.html');
});
```

Comment: "i want to see real-time value and know when did which value was sent" - please clarify.

Comment: can u just use nativeJS Date() in your console.log

Comment: @alfasin like 1second - value a , 2second - value b

Comment: @adamz4008 is it module??

Comment: this should be common across front/back end. check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

To see the "real" time in node js, you could use `new Date()` to get the date it will return something like that:

```
2017-12-14T09:00:34.359Z
```

And **because** it's a Date object, there are all the methods that you can find on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Or, if you want the exact time using timezone etc..., use the [Google Maps timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start)

Comment: thank you for reply. 
I want the port to open and the time the data comes in.

Comment: @kararara So you want to do a simple API?

Comment: I even implemented that when the port is opened, the data is logged. What I want to do is record the time while the program is running. Finally, What i want is a real-time graph

Comment: @kararara You just want a thing that logs the date for each request to your server. right?

Comment: @kararara Ok, it's easy, you Can just use `console.log(new Date())`

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the meaning. 0 seconds when the port is opened rather than the real time . and From that moment, let the time begin